# Printing PDF - How to add margin top and bottom on every page?

Tags: css, pdf, printing, media-queries

I'm using phantomjs to take a screen capture of a "Proposal" that my application creates. This is all going great, it exports to PDF fine.

When I print from PDF, I need to add margin top and margin bottom for EVERY page. Is there any form of CSS print property for this?

For instance, once the content of a page flows into the next page, it starts RIGHT at the top of the page. I need to have margin top here to solve that. Likewise for margin bottom.

[image]

See the grey bar going through my content? Thats where the page break is taking place. I need to add margin after the grey bar, and before it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up answering this myself if anyone is curious, Phantom JS comes with the option to add margins.

```
var marginTop = "75px";
var marginBottom = "85px";

page.paperSize = {
    format: 'A4',
    margin: {
            top: marginTop,
            bottom: marginBottom
        },
    orientation: 'portrait'};
```